# Information from two table in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables which are laid out like so....

Table1

```
+------+----------+-----+--------+
| Year |  Runner  | Age | Result |
+------+----------+-----+--------+
| 2004 | Runner 1 |   3 | Won    |
| 2004 | Runner 2 |   4 | Lost   |
| 2004 | Runner 3 |   3 | Lost   |
| 2005 | Runner 1 |   3 | Lost   |
| 2005 | Runner 2 |   3 | Lost   |
| 2005 | Runner 3 |   4 | Won    |
| 2006 | Runner 1 |   4 | Won    |
| 2006 | Runner 2 |   3 | Lost   |
| 2006 | Runner 3 |   4 | Lost   |
+------+----------+-----+--------+
```

Table2

```
+-------+----------+-----+
| RCNum |  Runner  | Age |
+-------+----------+-----+
|     1 | Runner 1 |   3 |
|     2 | Runner 2 |   4 |
|     3 | Runner 3 |   3 |
|     4 | Runner 4 |   3 |
|     5 | Runner 5 |   3 |
+-------+----------+-----+
```

Now I will use...

```
    $numbers = mysql_query("SELECT age,
        sum(case when result <> ''then 1 else 0 end) Sec1Picks,
        sum(case when result = 'Won' then 1 else 0 end) Sec1Wins
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY age
    ORDER BY age ASC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($numbers, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "(".$row['Age']."yo) ".$row['Sec1Wins']."-".$row['Sec1Picks']; }
```

Which will give me the age and then number of picks and winners but what I am trying to do is after this I want to include the RCNum of those which fall under that factor.

So for example 3yo would output..

(3yo) 1-5 (1 3 4 5)
(4yo) 2-4 (2)

My skills are basic so I am not sure how to go about achieving this so any help would be much appreciated! Thank You is advance!

**EDIT**

I am currently using...as suggested below

```
SELECT t1.age
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t1.result <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Sec1Picks
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t1.result = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Sec1Wins
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.rcnum ORDER BY rcnum SEPARATOR ' ') rcnums
  FROM table2 t2
  RIGHT
  JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.age= t2.age
 GROUP 
    BY t1.age;
```

Which gives me this...

```
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
|   age     | Sec1Picks | Sec1Wins |          rcnums           |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
|         3 |       420 |       14 | 8 9 13 21 22 25 27        |
|         4 |       352 |       24 | 6 7 11 16 17 19 20 29     |
|         5 |       470 |       10 | 1 2 3 5 10 15 18 23 24 26 |
|         6 |        64 |        6 | 12 14                     |
|         7 |        25 |        1 | 4                         |
|         8 |         7 |        0 | NULL                      |
|         9 |         2 |        0 | 28 30                     |
+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------------+
```

But what is happening is for each Number inserted in the rcnums column it is adding the stats again in the Picks/Wins column!

In the Picks/Wins columns I want to count in Table1 only so 3yo would be 60 and 2 not 420 and 14. How would I change the coding to achieve this?

Comment: I am sorry, but are these tables in separate databases? The title says so but it's not explicit in your question. For different databases, I assume different database instances

Comment: @Leo I think the OP meant 'tables'

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant, two tables into one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.age
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t1.result <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Sec1Picks
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t1.result = 'Won' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Sec1Wins
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.rcnum ORDER BY rcnum SEPARATOR ' ') rcnums
  FROM table2 t2
  LEFT
  JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.runner = t2.runner
 GROUP 
    BY t2.age;
```

Comment: I have noticed something that is not quite working with it now!

Say I am looking at the stats for 3yo runner which are 1-5..
This is being duplicated for each RCNum so if there are 4 in the rcnum column this number changes to 4-20 whereas I want it to remain as 1-5, anyway of fixing this?